# What is wrong with the web server that is shown in the rust documentation?

Tags: rust

I'm wanting to make a web server with rust, but I don't want to use a framework like rocket or hyper because they have much more than I need, and some don't have what I need. So I'm looking for a relatively basic web server.

### Why I'm looking for a relatively basic web server?

I'm not really going to use rust as a backend language, I'm going to use the FastCGI protocol to execute php files from a server written in rust. So I don't need a routing system or a template system like some frameworks have.

So seeing that some frameworks have more than what I'm looking for (and even though I know it's going to be complex) I want to write my own simple web server in rust. And then I remembered that [the documentation teaches how to do it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html). The problem comes in the link I passed, where the documentation explicitly says:

> Before we get started, we should mention one detail: the method we’ll
> use won’t be the best way to build a web server with Rust. Community
> members have published a number of production-ready crates available
> on crates.io that provide more complete web server and thread pool
> implementations than we’ll build.

Now that I have explained what and why I want to do this. What's wrong with the web server that the documentation shows? I've seen it a bit and it seems like a good thing to me, but I would like you to tell me what problems I can have if I implement a web server like the one shown in the documentation.

Comment: "*they have much more than I need*"—but the compiled binary will only include code that is actually used?

Comment: You may be interested in using [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) which is a relatively low-level http library that other web client/server libraries are built off of.

Comment: @kmdreko I did think about using hyper, but didn't because I couldn't find a way to get all the variables needed for a FastCGI request's environment variables, like REMOTE_ADDR or REMOTE_PORT

Comment: @eggyal Oh, if the binary only includes what is needed then maybe try using something like rocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "web server that the documentation shows" is not really a "web server". It's just a TcpListener that listens on a network interface and a port. To make a "web server" you have to implement the protocols HTTP/1.1 (rfc2616), HTTP/2 (rfc7540), HTTP/3 (rfc9114) and the SSL (rfc6101) and I probably forget a lot of things. You also need the FastCgi ([https://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eyandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html)) protocol for your project.

The code presented in the documentation is obviously a starting point but the path to something like a WebServer is far.

If you are looking for simplicity, a "php -S 127.0.0.1:7878" also does the trick. But it is not recommended in production.

Regards

Comment: But even for example in [this part of the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html), which shows http responses, is that still a TcpListener?

Comment: Yes, it's still a TcpListener.

Comment: I found this [projetct](https://lib.rs/crates/async-fcgi) perhaps it can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot then, this was the kind of answer I was looking for.